# form input name from mysql

Tags: php, mysql, forms, input

im create a survey system using php and mysql.. the problem here is i don't know how to pass the 'input name' when i click the submit button.

eg:

```
 1. Test 1
 <input type="text" name="name_{=$res[$a]['id']}">

 2. Test 2
 <input type="text" name="name_{=$res[$a]['id']}">
```

how to call the 'input name'?

```
 if(isset($_post['btnSubmit'])) {
    $xxx = $_post['name_????'];
    $yyy = $_post['name_????'];
 }
```

i replace the open/close php tag with {} because its not allowed..

edited

```
    <div class="form-body">
                    <h3 class="block"><?=$resSurvey[0]['survey_title']?></h3>
                    <p><?=$resSurvey[0]['survey_desc']?></p>
                    <br><br>

                    <?php
                        if ($rowQuestion >0) {
                            $bil=1;
                            for ($a=0; $a<$rowQuestion; $a++) {
                    ?>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="control-label col-md-3"><?=$bil?>. <?=$resQuestion[$a]['question_title']?></label>
                        <?php if ($resQuestion[$a]['question_type'] == 'tf') { ?>
                        <div class="radio-list col-md-4" >
                            <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="name_<?=$resQuestion[$a]['question_id']?>" value="t"> True </label>
                            <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="name_<?=$resQuestion[$a]['question_id']?>" value="f"> False </label>
                        </div>
                        <?php } ?>

                        <?php if ($resQuestion[$a]['question_type'] == 'st') { ?>
                        <div class="col-md-4">
                            <input type="text" name="name_<?=$resQuestion[$a]['question_id']?>" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter text">
                        </div>
                        <?php } ?>

                        <?php if ($resQuestion[$a]['question_type'] == 'lt') { ?>
                        <div class="col-md-4">
                            <textarea class="form-control" name="name_<?=$resQuestion[$a]['question_id']?>" rows="3"></textarea>
                        </div>
                        <?php } ?>

                        <?php 
                            if ($resQuestion[$a]['question_type'] == 'ms') {
                                $sqlOption = sprintf("select * from tbl_surveychoices where question_id=%d", mysql_real_escape_string($resQuestion[$a]['question_id']));
                                $resOption = selectSQL($sqlOption);
                                $rowOption = count($resOption);
                        ?>
                        <div class="radio-list col-md-4">
                            <?php for($b=0; $b<$rowOption; $b++) { ?>
                            <label class="radio"><input type="radio" name="name_<?=$resQuestion[$a]['question_id']?>" value="<?=$resOption[$b]['choices_id']?>"> <?=$resOption[$b]['choices_title']?></label>
                            <?php } ?>
                        </div>
                        <?php } ?>

                        <?php 
                            if ($resQuestion[$a]['question_type'] == 'mm') {
                                $sqlOption = sprintf("select * from tbl_surveychoices where question_id=%d", mysql_real_escape_string($resQuestion[$a]['question_id']));
                                $resOption = selectSQL($sqlOption);
                                $rowOption = count($resOption);
                        ?>
                        <div class="radio-list col-md-4">
                            <?php for($b=0; $b<$rowOption; $b++) { ?>
                            <label><input type="checkbox" name="name_<?=$resQuestion[$a]['question_id']?>[]" value="<?=$resOption[$b]['choices_id']?>">  <?=$resOption[$b]['choices_title']?> </label>
                            <?php } ?>
                        </div>
                        <?php } ?>
                    </div>
                    <?php
                                $bil++;
                            }
                        }
                    ?>
                </div>
```

Comment: how should we know?, we don't know what is inside $res[$a]['id'].

Comment: you are not helping @KoenHoeijmakers

Comment: Well, maybe supply us with the whole code instead?, if you don't know what is inside `$res[$a]['id']`, then how should we possibly know?

Comment: I would recommend looking here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9774406/retrieve-data-from-mysql-database-using-html-form-and-php-with-demo

Comment: im edit the question.. maybe it will help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would make it easier on yourself and make the input names have an index of ??? instead

```
 name="name_<?=$resQuestion[$a]['question_id']?>[]"
```

becomes

```
name="name['<?=$resQuestion[$a]['question_id']?>'][]"
```

Then on submit becomes

```
if(isset($_post['btnSubmit'])) {
   foreach ($_POST['name'] as $question_id => $values) {
      $xxx[$question_id] =  $values;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$inside = 'name_'.$res[$a]['id'];    
$xxx = $_POST[$inside];
```

Try this